# Python urllib2: Getting blocked from a website?

Tags: python, urllib2, blocked

I had been using urllib2 to parse data from html webpages. It was working perfectly for some time and stopped working permanently from one website.

Not only did the script stop working, but I was no longer able to access the website at all, from any browser. In fact, the only way I could reach the website was from a proxy, leading me to believe that requests from my computer were blocked.

Is this possible? Has this happened to anyone else? If that is the case, is there anyway to get unblocked?

Comment: This sounds like an IP ban, contact the party hosting the website and ask why you can't access their website anymore. Alternatively if you have a broadband router, sometimes unplugging that for an hour or so will give you a new IP, that will work around the problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible, maybe the sysadmin noticed that your IP was making way too many requests and decided to block it.

It could also be that the server has a limit of requests that you exceeded.

If you don't have a static IP, a restart of your router should reset your IP, making the ban useless.